# Parentheses in a file path prevent webpack watch from working

Tags: webpack

After a couple of hours unable to figure out why webpack --watch wasn't working, I ended up experimenting with the file path that includes the project folder and it worked.

It seems that having parentheses in the file path prevents --watch from working.

Example: C:\Users\User\stuff (stuff)\stuff\projectfolder\ is no good.

As long as the absolute file path (where the project folder is included) doesn't have parentheses everything works fine.

Is there any workaround? Is it bad practice to use parens in file paths? Gulp watch and jspm watch both work fine. Feel free to try for yourselves.

By the way I'm using Windows.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's already a bug opened for on the webpack issues list

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2258